# how to get phyiscal path of windows service using .net?

Tags: .net, windows-services, administration, servicecontroller

I have to get the absolute path of a windows service in a .Net Admin application. I am using ServiceController of .Net as shown below.

```
ServiceController serviceController = new  ServiceController(serviceName);
```

But I don't see any property here to get the absolute path of the .exe of the service. Is there anyway to get this programmatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get this using WMI, which requires an assembly reference to System.Management:

```
using System.Management;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetPathOfService("eventlog"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string GetPathOfService(string serviceName)
    {
        WqlObjectQuery wqlObjectQuery = new WqlObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", serviceName));
        ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlObjectQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectCollection)
        {
            return managementObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If it's not its own assembly you can look in the registry at:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\[servicename]\ImagePath
```

Or if you mean find your own assembly's path:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```