# Windows Service Source Files

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Is there any way to get the files associated with a windows service? Local and remote machine. In case of IIS i use the config file to get list of IIS services and their absolute path on the machine. Need to do this via code.

Thanks

EDIT: To make the question clear, i need to get the installation path of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics` has functionality to query running processes:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
    Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1} File {2}”, 
        theprocess.ProcessName, 
        theprocess.Id, 
        theprocess.MainModule.FileName);
}
```

If you want installed services rather then running processes you can use:

```
ServiceController.GetServices()
```

from `System.ServiceProcess`

you can get the file paths using the methodology described here: [how to get phyiscal path of windows service using .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728578/how-to-get-phyiscal-path-of-windows-service-using-net)

Comment: i was just going to update here that i achieved it using WMI ! Thanks for the link. I'll accept your answer.