# finding the actual executable and path associated to a windows service using c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working on an installation program for one of my company's product. The product can be installed multiple times and each installation represents a separate windows service. When users upgrade or reinstall the program, I would like to look up the services running, find the services that belong to the product, and then find the executable file and its path for that service. Then use that information to find which one of the services the user wishes to upgrade/replace/install/etc. In my code example below, I see the service name, description, etc, but don't see the actual filename or path. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

The code I have is as follows:

```
        ServiceController[] scServices;
        scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();

        foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
        {
            if (scTemp.ServiceName == "ExampleServiceName")
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("  Service :        {0}", scTemp.ServiceName);
                Console.WriteLine("    Display name:    {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);

                ManagementObject wmiService;
                wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + scTemp.ServiceName + "'");
                wmiService.Get();
                Console.WriteLine("    Start name:      {0}", wmiService["StartName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("    Description:     {0}", wmiService["Description"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can either use WMI or the registry. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728578/how-to-get-phyiscal-path-of-windows-service-using-net).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Gene! Using my example above and the link you posted I was able to do the following: wmiService.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString() which returned the full path and file name of the program that's being exeduted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I might be wrong but the `ServiceController` class doesn't provide that information directly.

So as suggested by Gene - you will have to use the registry or WMI.

For an example of how to use the registry, refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26533/A-ServiceController-Class-that-Contains-the-Path-t

If you decide to use WMI (which I would prefer),

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{    
    string name = obj["Name"] as string;
    string pathName = obj["PathName"] as string;
    ...
}
```

You can decide to wrap the properties you need in a class.

Answer (score 4):

the interface has changed since @sidprasher answered, try:

```
var collection = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
        .Where(mbo => mbo.GetPropertyValue("StartMode")!=null)
        .Select(mbo => Tuple.Create((string)mbo.GetPropertyValue("Name"), (string)mbo.GetPropertyValue("PathName")));
```