# How to find executable path of a windows service

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-services, executable-path

I am trying to find the executable path of a running service , and i have looked upon `ServiceBase` and there is no property indicating the path. Nor does `ServiceController offer any kind of help`.

```
ServiceBase []services=ServiceController.GetServices();
IEnumerable<string> paths=services.Select(x=> x. ? );
```

I have also tried using `sc qc` cmd command but it seems it does not work for a particular service

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.Arguments = "sc qc \"[service-name]\" | find \"BINARY_PATH_NAME\"";
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();
            var data = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

It throws the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'StandardOut has not been redirected
>   or the process hasn't started yet.'

Is there any way to get the path of the executable for a particular service or all of them ?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828588/finding-the-actual-executable-and-path-associated-to-a-windows-service-using-c-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **WMI**

For example (with [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572)):

```
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: {0}", queryObj["DisplayName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("PathName: {0}", queryObj["PathName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ProcessId: {0}", queryObj["ProcessId"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException me)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + me.Message);
            }
```