# Get service path from services.msc c#

Tags: c#, service, servicecontroller

I'm trying to get service executable path from services.msc

I wrote the next code:

```
  var service = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(p => p.ServiceName.Equals("Service name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
if (service.Any())
//get service data
```

I couldn`t find where (if at all) the service executable path is located?

In services.msc I can see the path so I'm assuming it also possible to get it through code.
[image: Example of service info in services.msc (see that executable path exists there)]

Any Ideas?

Comment: not sure if it will help this case, but it may help to look at the WindowsAPICodePack ShellFile class and see if it can help access this information

Comment: [**how to get phyiscal path of windows service using .net?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728578/how-to-get-phyiscal-path-of-windows-service-using-net) and [**A ServiceController Class that Contains the Path to the Executable**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26533/A-ServiceController-Class-that-Contains-the-Path-t)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it from the registry like so:

```
private static string GetServiceInstallPath(string serviceName)
{
    RegistryKey regkey;
    regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\{0}", serviceName));

    if (regkey.GetValue("ImagePath") == null)
        return "Not Found";
    else
        return regkey.GetValue("ImagePath").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI to get full information about your service (local or remote service)

Check the code of ( [Services+ on CodePlex](https://servicesplus.codeplex.com/) ) about how to use WMI

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit simplified version of @ChirClayton's code:

```
public string GetServiceInstallPath(string serviceName) => (string) Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\{serviceName}").GetValue("ImagePath");
```

It doesn't trim possible arguments of service. If they are not required, you can use following:

```
public string GetServiceInstallPath(string serviceName) 
{
    var imagePath = (string) Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\{serviceName}").GetValue("ImagePath");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
        return imagePath;
    if (imagePath[0] == '"')
        return imagePath.Substring(1, imagePath.IndexOf('"', 1) - 1);
    var indexOfParameters = imagePath.IndexOf(' ');
    if (indexOfParameters >= 0)
        return imagePath.Remove(indexOfParameters);
    return imagePath;
}
```